# VoiceOver does not parse DOM in React SPA?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, voiceover, screen-readers

I am using VoiceOver with `Google Chrome` and trying to figure out why moving from Page A -> Page B in a React SPA application (no hard page refresh, using HTML5 Push API via `react-router`) does not trigger a DOM parsing refresh for VoiceOver.

I checked using the `Accessibility Inspector` but when loading Page B the whole application is just considered as one big group with no children. If I turn off VoiceOver and turn it back on while on Page B then it magically becomes parsed.

This is not an issue on Safari.

Any ideas how I could nudge VoiceOver to parse the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `aria-live="polite"` attribute to the wrapper around the changing content should notify assistive technology whenever its contents has been changed.

For example adding that attribute to the parent surrounding of the `<Switch>` component will notify VoiceOver whenever any components is rendered by a `<Route>` component after navigation.

```
const Main = () => {
  <main aria-live="polite">
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
      <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
      <Route path='/contact' component={Contact}/>
    </Switch>
  </main>
};
```

[ARIA live regions - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions)